# How to set transition background in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

During some of the page transitions (for example during the turn and flow transitions) in jQuery Mobile a blank background/page is shown during the transitions.

For reference see: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

How does one change that blank background?

EDIT: Here's a JSfiddle to illustrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/4ayER/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can just set CSS for the body element:

```
body {
 background-color: blue !important;
}
```

EDIT: turns out it needs the !important part.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/4ayER/2/

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. It needs the !important part. I've updated the answer and made a fiddle that shows it working.

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

since using !important is not a best practice in CSS, you can avoid using it by adding this rule in your css:
    .ui-body-c, 
    .ui-overlay-c {
      background-color: blue;
    }